# Best of both world - MVC site and access to directory structure

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I have a combined website and web application on a domain, and I'd like to rewrite the website portion to use a more MVC framework like Symfony2.

I'd like to use the www.example.com/index.php/pagename approach which I could then replace with modrewrite to work as www.example.com/pagename.

Problem -- I am not prepared to refactor the entire web application. For example, there are sever folders with literal files that need to be accessed.

www.example.com/admin/dosomething.php

So I wondering about best ideas for rewriting index.php using something a little more attractive while preserving the file directory structure in the URLs.

Thoughts/options?

EDIT: To clarify, I want to rewrite example.com/index.php/page to something more professional while still allowing access to http://www.example.com/admin/file.php, an actual path. Looking for thoughts and best practices for that.

Comment: Specify which URLs you want to rewrite and to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default [.htaccess file from Symfony Standard Edition](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/.htaccess) handles this by checking for file existence before rewriting. The logic is roughly "if this request matches an existing file, don't rewrite... else, rewrite to app.php" (or in your case index.php).

It accomplishes this by using [rewrite conditions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) combined with a [rewrite rule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) with a - (dash) as the substitution (thus indicating that no substitution should be performed):

```
# If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]

# Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
RewriteRule .? app.php [L]
```

If you want to let existing directories be served directly too (instead of being redirected to index.php), use the -d switch, for example by adding this at the top:

```
# If the requested directory exists, simply serve it (except the root, which
# should also be rewritten - the ".+" pattern requires the path to be at least
# one character long, thus ignoring the root).
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]
```